# How to migrate a project to yarn flat mode?

Tags: node.js, ember.js, yarnpkg

We have a rather comprehensive ember-cli project with many dependencies, which wie manage with yarn. Now we'd like to convert it to yarn flat mode but yarn wants to convert all dependencies to flat mode and asks for dozens of dependencies for the version to use. Sometimes this is simple like choosing between 1.0.2 and 1.0.4. But there also cases where I have to choose between 0.0.3, 1.0.19 and 2.2.1 and whatever version I'll choose, something breaks. Due to the fact that yarn always converts the whole project and all dependencies it's rather complicated to debug which of the difficult version choosings actually breaks the whole app.

This is especially a problem with lodash 3 vs 4. lodash changed the module structure in version 4, so both major versions are really incompatible. Unfortunately in a normal ember-cli app there are lot of packages which depend on either lodash 3 or lodash 4 and neither of them work because the respective other dependency is broken.

Is there a way to do the migration in a "mixed" mode where some dependencies are managed flat and some not? This way I could migrate a single package to flat mode and test the app, run specs and so on and continue with the next package.

Also I'm very thankful for any advice that helps solving the lodash problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. The flat mode option is something that is being introduced slowly, but hasn't yet received heavy attention. My impression is the Yarn folks are working on making Yarn a good replacement for npm before they work on that major new feature heavily. As such, you may be hitting early adopter pains there ...